# Where To Store Public and Private Key files?

Tags: encryption, key-management, java, rsa, key

I'm creating a Java web-application using a WAR file to be deployed on a server. I will only be using one single web server and hosting.

In my project, I'm generating two files: Public Key file and Private Key file. On my localhost, I simply keep these files in a folder on my Desktop for convenience.

But when I deploy on my live server:

Should I store my Public and Private Key files within the same project folder? inside the WEB-INF? Or within the public html folder in FTP?

Comment: I believe the WEB-INF folder isn't accessible in from a user request standpoint, but can be accessed by the application using getResource and getResourceAsStream.  Why do you need a public and private keypair?  If we knew more about what the application is attempting to do that may help give you a better answer.  At this point the question is very broad.

Comment: I'm just using the keys to encrypt and decrypt application-level field values like social number, email, etc.  Only the application will be able to use it.